# MySQL - Correct Syntax for MySQL user defined function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created the following function but seem to be getting an error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION avg_month(shop INTEGER) RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    avg_m_sales DECIMAL
  SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(paymentdate) / 12),2) FROM sales_table 
  WHERE YEAR(paymentdate) = 2017 AND shopid = shop
RETURN avg_m_sales
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting the following error.

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(payid) / 12),2) FROM fss_Payment WHERE YEAR(paydate) ' at line 5`

I also tried adding `;` to the end of the statements but when I do this i get the following error:

`#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

Comment: Probably missing `;` at the end there on your statements.

Comment: @tadman Tried that but then get the following error `#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

Comment: Error seems pretty specific. Time to read up on why.

Comment: Why are you declaring `avg_m_sales` and returning it, but not actually assigning its value in the `SELECT` statement? (I don't know MySQL functions, but my guess would be that without the assignment to a variable, MySQL thinks you want to return the resultset of `SELECT` from the function, as would happen in a stored procedure.)

Comment: Try `SET avg_m_sales = (SELECT ... );`. Or just skip that `avg_m_sales` variable - `RETURN (SELECT ... )` might also work.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you didn't set a value for avg_m_sales
line number 4

```
     CREATE FUNCTION avg_month(shop INTEGER) RETURNS DECIMAL 
     BEGIN 
       DECLARE avg_m_sales DECIMAL;
         SET avg_m_sales=(
         SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(paymentdate) / 12),2) FROM sales_table
         WHERE YEAR(paymentdate) = 2017 AND shopid = shop);
       RETURN avg_m_sales;
     END;
```

EDIT : another answer

```
     CREATE FUNCTION avg_month(shop INTEGER) RETURNS DECIMAL 
     BEGIN 
         RETURN (SELECT TRUNCATE((COUNT(paymentdate) / 12),2) FROM sales_table
         WHERE YEAR(paymentdate) = 2017 AND shopid = shop);
     END;
```

Comment: You should be able to `SELECT` directly into the variable, e.g. `SELECT avg_m_sales = TRUNCATE((COUNT(paymentdate) / 12),2) FROM sales_table WHERE YEAR(paymentdate) = 2017 AND shopid = shop` without the `SET` and the subquery, I think.

Comment: i tried without `set` and it returns the same error
`Not allowed to return a result set from a function`

Comment: @MattGibson At least in MySql the `=` in `SELECT avg_m_sales = ..` is a boolean operator. What might work is `SELECT .. INTO (avg_m_sales) FROM ...`

Comment: he has to set `return` before `select` if he don't want to use `set`

Comment: That works. The only thing i had to change was swap around `shopid = shop` to `shop = shopid` as it would give error when I ran it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Ah, yeah, that's ringing bells now. I've been working with SQL Server and Oracle this month, so all the syntax is merging into one!

Comment: @HoldTight what is the difference between `shopid = shop` and `shop = shopid`

Comment: @AhmedTaha  `shop` is the variable being passed in and compared to `shopid` which is from my table.